# Combine MySQL results and show only the orders on a particular product

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, orders

I want to make a page for my shop's admin that shows orders on a particular product.
I already have all the orders and products having a 'reference' column being recorded in them which is unique. I tried the below query but it shows all of the products plus the requested product being shown an extra row. I just want the orders on the particular product being requested to be displayed. $_REQUEST['productid']; is getting the product id based on an admin page showing all products in a list and that info is being retrieved successfully.

```
$reference = $_REQUEST['productid'];
mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN orders ON orders.reference='".$reference."'");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has only the join, it's missing the WHERE statement:

```
$reference = $_REQUEST['productid'];
mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * 
  FROM products 
  INNER JOIN orders 
    ON orders.reference='".$reference."' 
  WHERE products.id = '".$reference."'");
```

Further, since you only want to retrieve the orders, you might want to rewrite it like this:

```
$reference = $_REQUEST['productid'];
mysqli_query($db,"SELECT orders.* 
  FROM orders
  INNER JOIN products 
    ON orders.reference=products.id 
  WHERE products.id = '".$reference."'"
  GROUP BY orders.id);
```

This is now a proper JOIN since it maps two fields from two tables. Also, since an order could possibly have two references to the same product, I added the optional GROUP BY statement so each individual order is only showed once (just delete that part if it's not necessary).

Comment: I kept getting this error:  Column 'reference' in where clause is ambiguous. But seeing the edit you made to the query, adding the table name before the column, I tried that and it fixed it. You're a genius! Thank you!

Comment: Plus of course the other edits such as the WHERE clause were right on as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> I just want the orders on the particular product being requested to be
>   displayed

Don't you want this?

```
$reference = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['productid']);
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE reference = " . $reference);
```